# Finding a limit converging into $\ln(x)$

Tags: integration, limits, logarithms

As we know, $\int\dfrac{1}{x}dx = \ln (x) + c$

Also, $\int x^a dx = \dfrac{x^{a+1}}{a+1} + c$ for any $a \neq -1$

But since $x^{-1} = \dfrac{1}{x}$, I suspected that $\ln x = \int\dfrac{1}{x}dx = \int x^{-1} dx = \lim_{a\to -1} \dfrac{x^{a+1}}{a+1}$

However this is false but I then realised this is pretty close from the real equality $\ln x = \lim_{a\to 0} \dfrac{x^a - 1}{a}$

But I don't manage to understand where does this $-1$ come from.
I know what I did was everything but rigourous, but is there a way to get this equality with a similar method to what I've done?

Thank you for reading!

Comment: The $-1$ can be incorporated into the constant of integration. That is, $\frac{x^a-1}{a}$ is as valid an anti-derivative of $x^{a-1}$ as $\frac{x^a}a$ is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably better to think to
$$
\ln x=\int_{1}^{x} \frac{1}{t}\,dt
$$
Since, for $a\ne -1$,
$$
\int_{1}^{x} t^a\,dt=\frac{x^{a+1}-1}{a+1}
$$
we can conjecture that
$$
\lim_{a\to-1}\frac{x^{a+1}-1}{a+1}=\ln x
$$
which is indeed true, because this is the derivative at $-1$ of the function
$$
f(a)=x^{a+1}
$$
and
$$
f'(a)=x^{a+1}\ln x
$$

When dealing with “indefinite integrals” it's common to get wrong conclusions, because of the constant of integration.

Answer (score 1):

Note that: $\ln x=\int \frac1x\,dx=\int x^{-1}\,dx=\lim_{a\to -1} \dfrac{x^{a+1}}{a+1}\color{BLUE}{+c}$

By setting $c=\lim_{a\to-1}-\frac1{a+1}$ we get the right value

Comment: I thought about that case, but then I don't understand why $c$ has to be $-\dfrac{1}{a+1}$ since the constant usually is arbitrary.

Comment: @QuentinJanuel the constant is **never** arbitrary!! It is true that when you integrate something you have an arbitrary constant but in this case you have the constant in an equation! If you want to show this using only integration and no equation then look at the first line you wrote: $\int \frac1x dx=\ln x\color{BLUE}{+c}$ and then by choosing $c=\lim_{a\to-1}\frac{1}{a+1}+k$ you really have an arbitrary constant, not $c$ but $k$. But when you say $\ln x=\int\frac1x dx$ you are setting and equation, where the variable is the integration constant

Comment: Alright, thank you I get it now. But how can we evaluate this constant? The @egreg reply made everything a lot more clear, however is this still possible to evaluate the constant to be$-\dfrac{1}{a+1}$ when using indefinite integrals?

Comment: The way @egreg used is computing $\ln x$ with the integral of $\frac1t$ by "avoiding" the constant. If you don't want to avoid the constant you can find it rather easily: if $\ln x=\lim_{a\to0}\frac{x^a-1}a=\int\frac1x=\lim_{b\to-1}\frac{x^{b+1}}{b+1}+c$, we have $a=b+1$ so we left with $\lim_{a\to0}\frac{x^a-1}a=\lim_{a\to0}\frac{x^a}a+c$. Now we can extend the left side: $\frac{x^a-1}a=\frac{x^a}a-\frac{1}a$ and hence we get to $\lim_{a\to0}\frac{x^a}a-\frac{1}a=\lim_{a\to0}\frac{x^a}a+c\implies \lim_{a\to0}-\frac{1}a=c$ now return it to expression with $b$, $c=\lim_{b\to-1}-\frac1{b+1}$

Answer (score 1):

Note that the derivative of $\frac{x^a-1}a$ is $x^{a-1}$, so $\frac{x^a-1}a$ is a valid anti-derivative of $x^{a-1}$. In fact, $\frac{x^a-1}a=\frac{x^a}a+C$, where $C=-\frac1a$.

Thus, it is reasonable to expect that
$$
\log(x)=\lim_{a\to0}\frac{x^a-1}a
$$
is an anti-derivative of $x^{-1}$.